# Android to many if and else conditions

Tags: android, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm using a shared preference to save users page number.  So when user reloads the app they can continue reading from where they left off. They way I have done it works but feels messy as this would end having like 400 if and else conditions. Is there a better way to do this. Many thx

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (firstcheck.getText().toString().equals("")){
        SavePrefs("FIRST_CHECK", firstcheck.getText().toString());
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ConfigurationActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        }else{
        if (firstcheck.getText().toString().equals("0")){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, BackgroundActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        }else{
        if (firstcheck.getText().toString().equals("1")){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Page1Activity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: why here you are saving string value instead integer?

Comment: I'm new to java and android so have a lot to learn still. guess its just a tutorial I followed and it seem to work for what I wanted to try and do. Will look into changing it to a integer as that would make sense. thx

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way of handling this is using enums.

```
public enum IfReplacement {
CASE_1("0") {

    public void handle(...) {
       //code for case "0" here.
    }

},
CASE_2("1") {

    public void handle(...) {
       //code for case "1" here
    }

};

    private static final Map<String, IfReplacement> VALUES;
    static {
       Map<String, IfReplacement> map = new HashMap<String, IfReplacement>();
       for(IfReplacement rep : IfReplacement.values()) {
          map.put(rep.key, rep);
       }
       VALUES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    private final String key;

    private IfReplacement(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public abstract void handle(... your parameters here ...)

    public static void handle(String key, ... your parameters here ...) {
        IfReplacement handler = VALUES.get(key);
        if(handler != null) {
          handler.handle(...);
        } else {
           //error or default logic here
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT:

This code was written in the browser so it may contain some typos. But the concept should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you go for **switch-case** in java? as it serves same function as you done using the many if-else conditions?

here is the official documentation on switch-case
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html